# How to restore a PostgreSQL database from within an SQL script

Tags: sql, postgresql, restore

How to restore a PostgreSQL database from within an SQL script.
I want to be able to restore a PostgreSQL using SQL or psql code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are working with pg_dump, then it can depend on how it was dumped.
If it was dumped to a text or sql file:

```
psql -U [user] -d [dbname] -1 -f <filename>.sql
```

Alternatively you can use pg_restore:

```
pg_restore -U [user] -d [dbname] [filename].dump
```

The following postgres [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/backup-dump.html#BACKUP-DUMP-RESTORE) might be helpful as well.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer, but what I´m looking for is a piece of sql code that allows me to restore a BD.
For instance 
Thinking in terms of :NET EntityFramework, I would like to be able to use something like this:
String command = “sql code to restore bd from a sql file”;
DALContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(command);